# Django TEMPLATEDOESNOTEXIST does not look under the app directory?

Tags: django

I looked at all TemplateDoesNotExist questions Google found me on Stackoverflow.  However, I could not solve this bug.

My installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'remarket',
    'polls',
)
```

Template Loader:

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = ('django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
 'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader')
```

But, when the request /polls/ comes in, Django only looks under admin and auth apps.  It does not look under the polls app to find the template under the app for the index.html.  This is straight from Django Poll App example.

Can anyone find out what it is that I am missing?

Also, I know how to 'make it work'.  You can simply move the template out of app's directory and into the project's directory.  Then, you can get TEMPLATE_DIR set to find it for you.  But, that takes away from re-usability of the app. So, please explain to me how we can fix it so we maintain the reusable app feature.

Comment: Do you really have `TEMPLATE_DIR` setting set? What if you rename it to `TEMPLATE_DIRS`?

Comment: And is your `TEMPLATE_DIRS` only pointing at your core template directory, or do you have the template directories for your apps included in there as well?

Comment: post details of your directory structure... are you aware that you need to put the app templates in a dir like: `myapp/templates/myapp/template.html` ?

Comment: @alexe, a correction, I did have TEMPLATE_DIRS and not TEMPLATE_DIR.  This is the structure: 'TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'templates').replace('\\', '/'),)
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = ('django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
 'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader')
STATIC_URL = '/static/' '

Comment: @souldeux - here it is: 'TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'templates').replace('\\', '/'),)'  So, I guess, it is pointing to the core template directory

Comment: alexe, souldeux, and Anentropic.  Here is the Template-loader postmortem message:  'Template Loader Error:
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
C:\Users\Ehsan\Web Development\Django\Examples\myproj\myproj\templates\polls\index.html (File does not exist)
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\polls\index.html (File does not exist)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\polls\index.html (File does not exist)'

Comment: Ok - it's looking in your core templates directory and the two built-in directories (contrib/admin and contrib/auth). If you have additional template directories that you want to load from, like from directly within specific apps, you'll need to include those in your TEMPLATE_DIRS as well. Please try this and let me know if it works. If it does, I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: souldeux, the tutorial on [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial03/) says that:           Django knows to find the polls templates even though we didn’t modify TEMPLATE_DIRS.  So, the point is not to manually add things to TEMPLATE_DIRS, but to let Django plug it in.  I think your answer is not the answer I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I had a `TemplateDoesNotExist` error, finding a template from a pluggable app ([wagtail_references](http://github.com/thclark/wagtail_references)). The error cropped up when I refactored my app out of another project and started installing it into my main project as a dependency.

The template loader postmortem showed it wasn't even looking in my app's `templates` dir.

My app was included in `INSTALLED_APPS`, and its AppConfig had a valid path.

The ultimate solution was that I hadn't packaged the app correctly... so the /templates/ directory was present on github but not in the builds! I'd missed off the `MANIFEST.in` file [from step 6 of the django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/reusable-apps/#packaging-your-app).

Adding the following `MANIFEST.in` file to the root of my package sorted it for me:

```
include LICENSE
include README.md
recursive-include wagtail_references/static *
recursive-include wagtail_references/templates *
recursive-include docs *
```

(and thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28863311/3556110) for helping me to find the way)

Answer (score 0):

Template loader **app_directories.Loader** is supposed to look under the app directory to find a template.  Note that this loader starts from **your_app/templates**.  Now, to use the namespacing concept in order to associate a certain template with a certain app, we create a subdirectory with the same name as the app, so that the path now looks like this: your_app/templates/your_app.

All templates for the app can then go in the 2nd **your_app** subdirectory. The “bug” is when you expect the template_name = ‘index.html’ be found under the 2nd **your_app** subdirectory, but Django will not find it there.

The way to address this is to know that the Loader starts from the templates directory of **your_app** subdirectory, so always name your template name starting from the template subdirectory:
**Template_names = your_app/index.html**

This is how it worked for me and I thought to share that with anyone who is running into the same problem. Please share if you have another way that works.