# After installing app TemplateDoesNotExist error

Tags: python, django

In virtualenv defaulting python3:
First I removed my app **myapp** from project. And I created a new folder called **django-myapp** next main django project directory.

Inside **django-myapp** I copied the **myapp** to this folder and created all needed files for making python package.

And I ran `python setup.py sdist`. Until now everything is ok.

My template and css files are included in **django-myapp-0.1.tar.gz** file. But when I installed this app with `pip install django-myapp/dist/django-myapp-0.1.tar.gz`, the app is installed. But when I run server and go to main page **TemplateDoesNotExist** error happens.

My admin page works, and then I checked **/env/alis5/lib/python3.4/site-packages/myapp/** there is no **templates** directory in it.

What is the problem. I followed django tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/reusable-apps/

here is my MANIFEST.in:

```
include LICENSE
include README.rst
recursive-include polls/static *
recursive-include polls/templates *
recursive-include docs *
```

and here is also my setup.py:

```
setup(
name='django-polls',
version='0.1',
packages=['polls'],
include_package_date=True,
license='BSD License', # example license
description='A simple Django app to conduct Web-based polls.',
long_description=README,
url='http://www.example.com/',
author='Maksat Yalkabov',
author_email='yalkabovmaksat@gmail.com',
classifiers=[
    'Environment :: Web Environment',
    'Framework :: Django',
    'Intended Audience :: Developers',
    'License :: OSI Approved :: BSD License', # example license
    'Operating System :: OS Independent',
    'Programming Language :: Python',
    # Replace these appropriately if you are stuck on Python 2.
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.2',
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.3',
    'Topic :: Internet :: WWW/HTTP',
    'Topic :: Internet :: WWW/HTTP :: Dynamic Content',
],
)
```

Comment: Are you sure you followed step 6 correctly and created a manifest file that included your templates?

Answer (score 1):

You said you followed the tutorial, but I have to ask, did you create the manifest file? You didn't mention it, and only Python is included by default.

Create `myapp/MANIFEST.in` and inside it add `recursive-include myapp/templates *`

That should ensure that `python setup.py sdist` creates the package with your templates directory recursively.

**edit**

Ok, so I've just tested this on a project of mine.

```
- proj
  - setup.py
  - MANIFEST.in
  - injurytracker
    - init.py
    - templates
    - etc
```

In `setup.py` I've got `packages=['injurytracker'],` to include my package, and in `MANIFEST.in` I've got `recursive-include injurytracker/templates *` And when I check the dist.gz I've got my templates included.

As you've mentioned `include_package_data`, setting that either way, doesn't effect the template directory inclusion.

In your `setup.py` also import `find_packages` from setuptools, and in your setup method add somthing like this;

```
packages=find_packages(exclude=["project", "project.*"]),
```

For me that picks out all my python modules & files that I expect, migrations included.

Comment: There's not much else to go on from what you've been able to provide. Are you able to zip up your source directory & host it? I could try and wrap it up on my machine, maybe make some more sense of things.

Comment: I wrote **include_package_date** instead of **include_package_data**. may be it is the cause of eror

Comment: In that link says that **Only Python modules and packages are included in the package by default. ** But when I look inside of tar.gz there is no **migrations** folder. I wonder why?

Comment: @MaksatYalkabov take a look at the `find_packages` example I've added to my answer.

Comment: ok I got it thank you for your answer, but one last thing: is it ok(I mean pythonic way) to include **migrations** folder (where python modules are in it) in **MANIFEST.in** file like `recursive-include polls/migrations *` instead of using **find_packages**. I used it like I mentioned and everything is ok but I want to know is it wrong to include python packages in MANIFEST.in. Or MANIFEST.in file is only for other file types?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this in your `settings.py`?

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader', # <--
)
```

Comment: I wrote **include_package_date** instead of **include_package_data**. Therefore  the error happened. When I corrected that the **template** problem is gone. :)